# Bootstrap : Clutter Columns In Concurrent Use Push & Pull Column Ordering

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I Have Problem With Concurrent Use `Push` & `Pull` Column Ordering Classes.

[I Want Ordering Columns Like This:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fv8qJ.png)

[But Result In `md` & `Larger` Screen Size is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ac3rg.png)

```
<section style="direction:rtl;">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8 col-md-3 col-md-push-9"><div class="well">Column 1</div></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-0 col-md-3 col-md-push-3"><div class="well">Column 2</div></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-8 col-md-3 col-md-pull-3"><div class="well">Column 3</div></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8 col-md-3 col-md-pull-9"><div class="well">Column 4</div></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-0 col-md-3 col-md-push-9"><div class="well">Column 5</div></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-8 col-md-3 col-md-push-3"><div class="well">Column 6</div></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8 col-md-3 col-md-pull-3"><div class="well">Column 7</div></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-0 col-md-3 col-md-pull-9"><div class="well">Column 8</div></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-8 col-md-3 col-md-push-9"><div class="well">Column 9</div></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8 col-md-3 col-md-push-3"><div class="well">Column 10</div></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-0 col-md-3 col-md-pull-3"><div class="well">Column 11</div></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-8 col-md-3 col-md-pull-9"><div class="well">Column 12</div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can  you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset the push and pulls for md and lg screens that are carrying over from the sm screens.

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8 **col-md-push-0** col-md-3 col-md-pull-9"><div class="well">Column 4</div></div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/1NedaZMxUf

Comment: Thanks . its working correctly .But When I use `style="direction:rtl;` for `<section>` This Problem Happen again.
This kind Layout is for Language I Used in Page .My Language direction is `Right To Left` .

Comment: I don't know what language that is or if it's correct or not but maybe just float it to the right? If this answer worked, please accept it as an answer.

Comment: Here is a revised fiddle that works. I had to reset the pulls to zero for md devices. http://www.bootply.com/upsFDj9a27